# AudioContext .ended not firing properly

Tags: javascript, audiocontext

I have a simple routine that creates an audiocontext node and loads it with a buffer.  The onended event seems to fire at the start.  I set a timer for the duration and the onended event triggers about that amount of time before the audio stops playing.  Anybody know how to get a true onended event.   I tried to use the destination as well as the source, same result

```
function playSoundFile(buffer) {
   'use strict';
   audioCtx.close();
   audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
   audioSource = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
   audioSource.connect(audioCtx.destination);
   audioSource.buffer = buffer;
   audioSource.playbackRate.value = 1;
   stillPlaying(true);
   audio_player = audioCtx.destination;
   audioSource.addEventListener('onended', whatsUp());
   console.log('start ' + showTime());
   filePlayed(buffer.duration);
   audioSource.start();
}
```

the timestamp is only 1 ms different between the play and the onended event.
filePlayed starts a timeout event to show time at beginning and end.

Comment: Note, the code at Question calls `whatsUp()` immediately instead of referencing the function to call at an event.

Comment: Substitute `audioSource.addEventListener('onended', whatsUp);` for `audioSource.addEventListener('onended', whatsUp());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, guest271314 had it mostly right.

the documentation is confusing.  The eventListener is "ended" not "onended" and you have to use function name with the parans

so

```
audioSource.addEventListener('ended', whatsup);
```

takes care of the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Please accept your own answer as correct as a way for other people to know. Thanks.